# How to get highlighted text with legends as html output?

Tags: python, html

I have the below input from which I need to generate html output with highlighted text with legends for each color.

```
inp = [('Python', 'language'),
('is', 'others'),
('a', 'others'),
('programming', 'others'),
('language', 'others'),
('.', 'others'),
('John', 'Person'),
('is', 'others'),
('an', 'others'),
('excellent', 'Modifier'),
('coder', 'others'),
('based', 'Action'),
('out', 'others'),
('of', 'others'),
('California', 'location'),
('.', 'others')]
```

I want to generate a good basic html output by using Python and without using CSS or JS scripts.

I wrote the following code.

```
def nercolor(out):
import webbrowser
from random import shuffle

htmlcolor = ['#00FFFF', '#FF0000', '#ADD8E6', '#00FF00', '#FF00FF', '#FFA500', '#008000', '#808000', '#736AFF', '#368BC1', '#95B9C7', '#7FFFD4', '#728C00', '#FFA62F', '#827839', '#C36241', '#F75D59', '#7E354D']

shuffle(htmlcolor)
clt = []
for i,j in out:
    if j != 'others':
        clt.append(j)

COLOR = htmlcolor[:len(clt)]
d = dict(zip(clt, COLOR))

strh = "<html>"
for i,j in out:
    if j == 'others':
        strh += i
        strh += " "
    if j != 'others':
        strh += "<strong><span style='background-color:%s'>" % d[j]
        strh += i
        strh += "</span></strong>"
        strh += " "
strh += "</html>"

#Legends

COLOR = COLOR[:len(clt)]
lang = ['language', 'Person', 'location']
cl = list(zip(COLOR, lang))

stri = ''
stri += "<table>"
for j, i in d.items():
    stri += '<tr>'
    stri += "<td <span style='background-color: %s'>__________</span>&nbsp;</td>" %i
    stri += "<td>%s</td>" %j
    stri += '</tr>'
stri += "</table>"

new = stri+strh
log_file = open('/home/nms2kor/Documents/graphs/testcasecc3.html', 'w')
log_file.write(new)
return webbrowser.open('/home/nms2kor/Documents/graphs/testcasecc3.html')

nercolor(result)
```

I got the below output html from my code.

[image: screenshot of image]

But I want to generate somewhat better html output with line spacing between text, alignment of highlighted text to the left and legends to the right in a proper way.

It might be easy to design it using html, but my requirement is to generate it using python coding.

Comment: Out of curiosity; You are using HTML for the above, where do you draw the line for use of HTML. What I mean is how are we going to know when? Also, have you considered outputting an image instead? Then you will be able to avoid using HTML entirely.

Comment: You can create a table in html; then alignment and positioning will be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def nercolor(out):
    import webbrowser
    from random import shuffle

    htmlcolor = ['#00FFFF', '#FF0000', '#ADD8E6', '#00FF00', '#FF00FF', '#FFA500', '#008000', '#808000', '#736AFF', '#368BC1', '#95B9C7', '#7FFFD4', '#728C00', '#FFA62F', '#827839', '#C36241', '#F75D59', '#7E354D']

    shuffle(htmlcolor)
    clt = []
    for i,j in out:
        if j != 'others':
            clt.append(j)

    COLOR = htmlcolor[:len(clt)]
    d = dict(zip(clt, COLOR))

    strh = "<html><div style='width:70%;display:inline-block'>"
    for i,j in out:
        if j == 'others':
            strh += i
            strh += " "
        if j != 'others':
            strh += "<strong><span style='background-color:%s'>" % d[j]
            strh += i
            strh += "</span></strong>"
            strh += " "
    strh += "</div></html>"

    #Legends

    COLOR = COLOR[:len(clt)]
    lang = ['language', 'Person', 'location']
    cl = list(zip(COLOR, lang))

    stri = '<div style="width:20%;display:inline-block">'
    stri += "<table>"
    for j, i in d.items():
        stri += '<tr>'
        stri += "<td><span style='background-color: %s'>__________</span>&nbsp;</td>" %i
        stri += "<td>%s</td>" %j
        stri += '</tr>'
    stri += "</table></div>"

    new = stri+strh
    log_file = open('path/testcasecc3.html', 'w')
    log_file.write(new)
    return webbrowser.open('path/testcasecc3.html')

nercolor([('Python', 'language'),
('is', 'others'),
('a', 'others'),
('programming', 'others'),
('language', 'others'),
('.', 'others'),
('John', 'Person'),
('is', 'others'),
('an', 'others'),
('excellent', 'Modifier'),
('coder', 'others'),
('based', 'Action'),
('out', 'others'),
('of', 'others'),
('California', 'location'),
('.', 'others')])
```