# Highlighting Text and outputting to HTML

Tags: javascript, python, html, css

So basically this is my current code. My objective is to colour code text as shown in the picture down below. I am working on a virtual server.

In order to colour code the text and display it on the website interface, how do I have to go about it?

I tried using nested for loops and if statements and it didn't work.

```
var words = jresp.POS1;
    console.log(words);

    for(let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) //iterate through the rows
    {
        if(words[i][1] == 'ADJ')
            words[0].style.background = "#800000";
        else if(words[i][1] == 'ADV')
            words[0].style.background = "#aaffc3";
        else if(words[i][1] == 'ADP')
            words[0].style.background = "#ff00ff";
        else if(words[i][1] == 'CONJ')
            words[0].style.background = "#9a6324";
        else if(words[i][1] == 'DET')
            words[0].style.background = "#dcbeff";
        else if(words[i][1] == 'NOUN')
            words[0].style.background = "#469990";
        else if(words[i][1] == 'NUM')
            words[0].style.background = "#00ffff";    
        else if(words[i][1] == 'PRT')
            words[0].style.background = "#aaffc3";
        else if(words[i][1] == 'PRON')
            words[0].style.background = "#500080"; 
        else if(words[i][1] == 'PUNK')
            words[0].style.background = "#b40000";
        else if(words[i][1] == 'VERB')
            words[0].style.background = "#5f83ba";   
        else 
            words[0].style.background = "#727272"
    }

    document.getElementById("wOutput").innerHTML = words;
    console.log(words)
```

*Brief Overview of the Program*

The program gets an input from the user via submit. The text is then passed to the js script and then POST to the python script. The python script will detect the language, tokenize the text and POS_TAG the tokenized text. It will then return the list to the JS file as JSON and output the POS_TAG to the HTML user interface. The output would include the inputted string and the highlighted words as shown in the picture below.

Below is the Python Script

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import cgi;
import json;
import langdetect
import nltk

nltk.data.path.append('/home/amifsud02/nltk_data/')

from langdetect import detect
from nltk import tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

def getPostDataAsJson (environ):

    #form = cgi.FieldStorage()
    #text = form.getvalue("post-text")

    post_json = {};
    storage = cgi.FieldStorage (fp=environ['wsgi.input'], environ=environ, keep_blank_values=True);
    for k in storage.keys():
        post_json[k] = storage.getvalue(k);

    return (post_json);

def application (environ, start_response):
    form_params = getPostDataAsJson (environ);

    #Adding strings to the response body
    conttype = 'application/json';
    
    text = form_params["parainput"]
    errorMessage = ("The String Inputted is not in english")

    if detect(text) == 'en':

        tokenWord = word_tokenize(text)

        POS1 = nltk.pos_tag(tokenWord, tagset = 'universal')
        POS2 = nltk.pos_tag(tokenWord)

        taggedText = nltk.chunk.tree2conlltags(nltk.ne_chunk(POS1))
       
        data = {}
        data = {
            "Language": detect(text),
            "POS1": POS1,
            "POS2": POS2,
            "Tagged Text": taggedText
            "Coloured String": colouredString           
        };   

        response_body = [bytes(json.dumps(data), encoding='utf-8')];

        print(data)
    else:
        response_body = [bytes(json.dumps(errorMessage), encoding='utf-8')];


    
    #find the content-length (sum of all strings' lengths)
    content_length = sum([len(s) for s in response_body]);

    status = '200 OK'
    
    response_header = [('Content-type',conttype), ('Content-Length', str(content_length))];

    start_response (status, response_header)
    return response_body;
```

Below is the JS Script

```
function postFieldDataToOurServer()
{
    var fdata = new FormData ();
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest ();
    var jresp;
    var parainput = document.getElementById("parainput");

    console.log(parainput.value);


    //Populate the data we are going to send
    fdata.append("parainput", parainput.value);
    
    //send the data
    request.open("POST", "/python3", false);
    request.send(fdata);
    
    //recieve and parse the output Data
    jresp = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    
    
    var output = jresp.POS1 + "<br/>" + " ";
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
      
    console.log(jresp);
}
```

Below is a snippet of the HTML Script

```
 <div class = "outputBox mt-2" style = "max-width: 30%;">
                            <div id="output"></div>    
                        </div>
```

Wanted Output:
[image]

I also tried to make use of this forum too:
[How to get highlighted text with legends as html output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54167136/how-to-get-highlighted-text-with-legends-as-html-output)
but I did not understand that much since it did not make use of javascript

Comment: I don't know what you have in `words` but I don't understand: you check `words[i][1]` but you change style for `words[0].style` - why not for `words[i].style` or `words[i][1].style`

Comment: maybe you should use more `console.log()` and check values in all variables. And the same with `print()` in Python.

Comment: What I am doing is checking the json file. If for example there is "Italy", "NOUN". I am comparing the value of NOUN and then adding a background color to Italy since it is a noun.

Comment: but `words[0].style` is changing style always for the same first element - `[0]`, not for element with current word - `[i]`. But I don't know what is `words` - if it is normal array/list with normal strings then changing `style` can make no sense. It would have to be array/list with `HTML Elements`.